# Text-overflow strange behaviour with different fonts

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I made a simple website to demonstrate this behaviour:

```
 <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="./site.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <title>Document</title>
 </head>
<body>
   <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
        <span class="label label-primary"> LABEL </span> 
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa //overflowed text
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
```

and css:

```
.list-group-item {
  overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;  // if i comment this line it works
}

a {
  float:right;
}

.label {
   float:right;
   margin-right: 6px;
}
```

Result with `"Open Sans"`

[image: Result with <code>"Open Sans"</code>]

With `"Helvetica Neue"`

[image: "Helvetica Neue"]

Is that right? How to make it works with `Open Sans`?

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't reproduce the problem - all items end with ellipsis if it doesn't have enough space. What OS and browser are you using?

```css
.list-group-item {
  overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;
  max-width: 300px;
}
.helvetica {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}
.open-sans {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;  
}
a {
  float:right;
}

.label {
   float:right;
   margin-right: 6px;
}
```

```html
 <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="./site.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <title>Document</title>
 </head>
<body>
   <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
        <span class="label label-primary"> LABEL </span> 
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa //overflowed text
    </li>
     <li class="list-group-item open-sans">
        <a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
        <span class="label label-primary"> LABEL </span> 
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa //overflowed text
    </li>
     <li class="list-group-item helvetica">
        <a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
        <span class="label label-primary"> LABEL </span> 
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa //overflowed text
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Can confirm; `text-overflow` seems to operate as expected regardless of font selection.  See Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yg5u623v/

Comment: im using Windows 10 with google chrome. I didnt post on jsfiddle or other because i cannot reproduce it, but try to make a folder with these two files exactly how i posted here and run locally in your browser.

Comment: Tried it locally - everything works as expected. Is it possible that you didn't have that `text-overflow: ellipsis;` while trying it with open sans?

Comment: no, my files are exactly like i posted here, using the google opes sans. When I comment the ´font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;´ line, i works as expected.